# CMake can't find Python Development directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, cmake, realsense

I want to install `librealsense v2.50` on `Jetson Xavier nx dev-kit` with `ubuntu 20.04` with python bindings as follows:

```
~/Downloads/librealsense-2.50.0/build$ cmake ../ -DFORCE_LIBUVC=true\
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release \
-DBUILD_WITH_CUDA=true -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=true\
-DBUILD_NODEJS_BINDINGS=true -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3\
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DBUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES=true\
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.8 \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so
```

I get the following output:

```
CMake Warning:
-- Checking internet connection...
-- Internet connection identified
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (MESSAGE):
  FORCE_LIBUVC, FORCE_WINUSB_UVC and ANDROID_USB_HOST_UVC are deprecated, use
  FORCE_RSUSB_BACKEND instead


-- Info: REALSENSE_VERSION_STRING=2.50.0
-- Setting Unix configurations
-- Info: Building with CUDA requires CMake v3.8+
-- CUDA_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/cuda-11.4/include /usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcudart_static.a;Threads::Threads;dl;/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so;/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcusparse.so;/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcublas.so
-- Building libcurl enabled
-- using RS2_USE_LIBUVC_BACKEND
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/marvin/Downloads/librealsense-2.50.0/build/external-projects/pybind11
[ 12%] Performing update step for 'pybind11'
[ 25%] No patch step for 'pybind11'
[ 37%] No configure step for 'pybind11'
[ 50%] No build step for 'pybind11'
[ 62%] No install step for 'pybind11'
[ 75%] Completed 'pybind11'
[100%] Built target pybind11
-- pybind11 v2.6.2
```

Then I get an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_INCLUDE_DIRS Development
  Development.Module Development.Embed) (found version "2.7.18")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPython.cmake:622 
(find_package_handle_standard_args)
  wrappers/python/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)
```

I have solved this error before by removing the `Development` directory from the cmake find python, but I can't find it now, can you please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message mentions a `Python_INCLUDE_DIRS`, but you passed a `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR`. [The `FindPython` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) say to set `Python_INCLUDE_DIR`

Comment: @user I have tried both, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I have removed the `Development` directory from the [python wrapper cmake file](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/CMakeLists.txt#L63) and it worked for me.